# DNS routing not working on Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I'm trying to setup a custom domain for my Heroku Cedar stack app, but it's not working.

I've tried entering 'host www.mydomain.com' command' in Terminal, but it yields no output.

I've already changed my DNS settings and added a 'CNAME' host: www, direct to: my domain.herokuapp.com but still it's not working.

What could I be doing wrong here???

Thanks,

Faisal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're not getting any results in terminal for `host` then the problem lies with your DNS settings - it sometimes takes a while for updates to propogate across the internet, I usually allow for 24 hrs to be sure. If it still doesn't work then you should get in touch with your DNS host.

Comment: thanks! its fixed now; didn't do anything, just took some time for the DNS settings to propagate, as you said..

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add domain entries to your Heroku app:

```
heroku domains:add yourdomain --app yourapp
```

The "-app yourapp" is not required if you are in the root directory of your Rails app.

You can repeatedly add more than one domain to your Heroku app.

Here is an article about adding custom domains and DNS setup, at the Heroku Dev Center:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains